# Call data loader from a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, data-loader

I'm trying to build a lightning component that would replicate data loader/data wizard functionality. Is there a way we can integrate data loader into a lightning component? I want users to upload csv files directly from a custom page rather than using a data loader.

Thanks!

Comment: Curious as why do you need this? Why not use data import wizard? Remember you cannot anyways integrate the good old on-premise data loader to be invoked from a cloud based platform generically.

Comment: Not OP, but he might need to allow users to import records in which they do not have direct access to (if that makes any sense). To import custom objects you need the "Import Custom Objects" permission alongside with the Create and Edit permissions for said object, for example.

Comment: @JayantDas Very true but we have a requirement for users to upload the files directly on the detail page of the record instead of navigating to Setup menu.

Comment: Here's my take -- You should rather negotiate on the UX with the Users. If Users want the capability to load records, that means they are well versed with the considerations for record upload. I usually do not recommend an end User/Business User to load records. So by restricting the "full setup" features, just educate them on how they can do that by using import wizard. That will be of less investment rather than trying to invest in a solution which serves the purpose that is already served using OOTB methodologies.

Comment: Using a canvas app helps? Sorry just throwing it out there

Answer (score 0):

You can use an third-party library like [PapaParse](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse) to handle your CSV on  the front-end, in JavaScript, and then send the data to the server as batches (chunks of, say, 200 records at a time) to be handled by Apex.

Note that if you want to use a component to upload different sets of data (for different objects) you'll have a hard time creating a method for your Apex code to insert/update the data into the correct tables.

Comment: Its just for one object every time.

Comment: Using a canvas app helps? Sorry just throwing it out there?